# Unable to add Reference of Fakes under Reference

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes

I am writing test case for my PR.Business project. Also added reference of the project in my test project.
Now I want to create shim of the methods in the appropriate class.
I have added a fakes by using "Add Fakes Assembly" of a project PR.Business. Fakes of file is added under Fakes folder, but it doesn't gets added or affects Reference tab of project.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you please specify?

Comment: I don't get any error. The fakes is added under Fakes folder just below Reference option. But the same should gets reflected under reference option. which is not done.

Comment: Try right clicking on `References` and then adding the assembly

Comment: Thanks Junaid but there is no option for adding assembly. And Assembly is already added under Fakes Folder but same has to be reflected under references, which is not visible.

Comment: Do you have a premium version of VS?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Try right clicking on the `References` option in the solution and then add the assembly.